# ElasticSearch match on list of int and string

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am fairly new to ElasticSearch and I am trying to make a query for our category page, where every product returned by ES, is in the category. For some reason, it includes products outside of the category, and I cannot seem to figure out why.

Product is a basic product, containing a list of category ids (the product can be in multiple categories). Apart from matching on categoryId, it should search in product name and the long description of the variants.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<Product> GetByCategory(string value, int take, int categoryId)
    {
        value = string.Format("*{0}*", value);

        var query = new SearchDescriptor<Product>()
            .Index(this.index)
            .Query(q => q
              .Bool(b => b
                .Must(s => s
                  .Match(m => m
                    .Field(ff => ff
                      .AttachedCategoryIds.Contains(categoryId)
                    )
                  )
                )
                .Must(s => s
                  .QueryString(m => m
                    .Query(value)
                      .Fields(ff => ff
                        .Field(f => f.Name)
                        .Field(f => f.Variants.Select(input => input.LongDescription))
                      )
                      .Type(TextQueryType.CrossFields)
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
              .Size(take)
              .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score));

        var data = client.Search<Product>(query);

        var products = data.Documents;

        return products;
    }
```

I expect to get only products from the current category back from elastic, but for some reason, it gives me products, that are not in a category/in a different category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct. Assuming the following POCOs

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> Variants { get; set; }
    public List<int> AttachedCategoryIds { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

The query would be something like

```cs
var index = "index_name";
var categoryId = 1;

var value = "this is the query";
var take = 20;

var query = new SearchDescriptor<Product>()
    .Index(index)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(s => s
                .QueryString(m => m
                    .Query(value)
                    .Fields(ff => ff
                        .Field(f => f.Name)
                        .Field(f => f.Variants.First().LongDescription)
                    )
                    .Type(TextQueryType.CrossFields)
                )
            )
            .Filter(f => f
                .Term(ff => ff.AttachedCategoryIds, categoryId)
            )
        )
    )
    .Size(take)
    .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score));

var searchResponse = client.Search<Product>(query);
```

Some points

1. `.Field(f => f.Variants.First().LongDescription)` is an *expression* that will resolve to a string that will be serialized in JSON to target a field in Elasticsearch. In this case, this will resolve to `"variants.longDescription"`
2. A [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) can be used to determine if a field in Elasticsearch contains a particular value. I've put the query into a `bool` query filter clause because I don't think you want to calculate a relevancy score for this part of the query i.e. a document either has the term in a field or it doesn't.

This serializes to the following query

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index_name/product/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "attachedCategoryIds": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "variants.longDescription"
            ],
            "query": "this is the query",
            "type": "cross_fields"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This query makes the assumption that `Variants` on `Product` is mapped as an `object` datatype. It can be more [succinctly written](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) as

```
var query = new SearchDescriptor<Product>()
    .Index(index)
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(m => m
            .Query(value)
            .Fields(ff => ff
                .Field(f => f.Name)
                .Field(f => f.Variants.First().LongDescription)
            )
            .Type(TextQueryType.CrossFields)
        ) && +q
        .Term(ff => ff.AttachedCategoryIds, categoryId)
    )
    .Size(take)
    .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score));
```